# Vuex -- Help me understand the behavior of array findIndex

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, single-page-application

I'm having trouble with the following code (will explain after) within a Vue SPA component:

```js
const accountArray = Array.from(Object.values(this.accounts)[0]) // [0 is the sub-array I need, and won't change]
const urlId = this.$route.params.id // 3
const i = accountArray.findIndex(account => account.id === urlId) // -1

console.log(i) // -1, as it didnt found any matches
console.log(urlId) // 3
```

The `this.accounts` is a computed property that returns an Observable object, and it works as expected (the 0 index is the sub-array of interest), hence my looping on it. The `accountArray` variable also returns the array that I want to iterate over (it has an account with id = 3), but when it comes to the iteration predicate, it **ALWAYS** returns `-1` when it should be returning `2`. Also, if I hard-code 3 instead of `urlId`, it returns the `2` that I'm looking for. Why?

When I print the `accountArray`, the output is the following:

> [image]

I've made sure that this is not a Vuex reactivity problem, because I can refresh the page and it still returns me the arrays I need. What I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure its not a reactivity problem?  When console logging the output is not always in sync with value the time that it was printed.  Try: console.log([ ...accountArray ]) to ensure the value is actually what you expect it to be.

Comment: @JustinLevine hey, it was a comparison problem, but thanks anyway for your input. I actually didn't know this trick to see exactly what value I'm working with. You also helped me =)

Comment: Yeah, no problem.  I ran into this issue debugging so many times in the past that caused a lot of headaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `===` comparison which expects the same value and same data type which is not true for your case. Your `account.id` is number and your `urlId` coming from route params is a string (`3 !== "3"`).

Try converting route params id to a number before comparing it to `account.id`.

```
const urlId = +this.$route.params.id // 3
```

Notice **+** sign in front of `this.$route.params.id` used to convert a string to a number.

As an alternative, you could compare it using `==` which would return true for your `3 == "3"` case, but I suggest you to stick to the first advice.

Comment: @Miranda I'm always glad to make a day better for someone. :)

Comment: I went to sleep at 4am because of this problem that appeared last night! You saved my day, man!